# aws cloudwatch log for elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

From webapp, end-user will specify start time and end time for fetching logs (either in .zip format or to just display log in new tab). I want to use cloudwatch for logging of elasticbeanstalk. What are the available JAVA api's for doing this. like enabling cloudwatch log in elasticbeanstalk and creating log stream etc

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want use java api? You can follow the below step to install & configure cloud-watch log in EB ENV.

1. You should add cloud-watch policy with your elastic beanstalk ec2 role.
2. Write config in .ebextension to install & configure the cloud-watch logs on EB based servers.

**Example config for cloud-watch log installation & configuration:**

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

container_commands:
  01_get_awslogs_conf_file:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/awslogs.conf /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf"
  03_restart_awslogs:
    command: "sudo service awslogs restart"
  04_start_awslogs_at_system_boot:
    command: "sudo chkconfig awslogs on"
```

3. Your awslogs.conf should be available in .ebextensions directory.

**Example file of awslogs.conf**

```
[general]
state_file = value
logging_config_file = value
use_gzip_http_content_encoding = [true | false]

[logstream1]
log_group_name = value
log_stream_name = value
datetime_format = value
time_zone = [LOCAL|UTC]
file = value
file_fingerprint_lines = integer | integer-integer
multi_line_start_pattern = regex | {datetime_format}
initial_position = [start_of_file | end_of_file]
encoding = [ascii|utf_8|..]
buffer_duration = integer
batch_count = integer
batch_size = integer
```

If you are not getting log under cloud-watch log on AWS console then check the agent log on your server. Agent default log path will be **/var/log/awslogs.log**

Hope, This will help you to setup cloud watch log on EB.

Comment: When elastic beanstalk is launched it automatically installs cloudwatch agent. I added configuration file but not working